# I don't understand this proof of comb space not local contractibility in (0,1).

Tags: algebraic-topology

I asked my teacher about the proof of $\require{cancel} Id_P \cancel{\simeq}_{_{\{(0,1)\}}} c_{(0,1)} $, this is that the identity function in $$P=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(\{\frac{1}{n}\}\times[0,1])\cup(\{0\}\times[0,1])\cup([0,1]\times\{0\})$$ is not homotopic relative to the set $\{(0,1)\}$ with the constant function where the constant is the point $(0,1)$.

He explained me a proof that I still don't understand:

"Let $H:P\times [0,1] \to P, ((x,y),0) \mapsto (x,y), ((x,y),1) \mapsto (0,1)$ be a continuous function. So, $\gamma_n(t):= H((\frac{1}{n},1),t)$ is a path in $P$ between $(\frac{1}{n},1)$ and $(0,1)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. We have to prove that exists $t_n \in [0,1]$ such that $\gamma_n(t_n)=(0,0)$ and then choose the limit point $s\in[0,1]$ of the sequence $\{t_n\}$. It's clear that $\gamma_n([0,1])\subset P$ for every $n\in \Bbb N$.

So, exists $m\in \Bbb N'\subset \Bbb N$ such that #$\Bbb N'=\infty$ and $t_m\in[0,1]$ which verifies $\gamma_m(t_m)=(0,0)$. Then, exists a subset $\Bbb N' \subset \Bbb N$ such that #$\Bbb N'=\infty$ and $\lim\{t_m\}=s.$"

I don't understand why it's needed that $m$ and the subset $\Bbb N'$ instead of the whole $\Bbb N$ and I think that a sequence $\{t_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ would be suitable to obtain that $s\in[0,1]$ to prove that $(0,1)$ isn't a fixed point for $H$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your prof's proof, but the subtlety is that $Id_p\not\simeq c_{(0,1)}$ by a *based* homotopy. Indeed, the comb space is pointed contractible when based at $(0,0)$, and this is freely joined to $(0,1)$ by a straight path, so $id_P$ and $c_{(0,1)}$ are clearly homotopic as *free* maps. The point is that we can't fix $(0,1)$ when forming a contracting homotopy. Make sure to take into account the fact that $H$ must be a based homotopy.

Comment: With "based homotopy", you mean a homotopy with fixed points?

Comment: If $(X,x_0)$, $(Y,y_0)$ are based spaces, each with a distinguished basepoint, then a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is said to be based, or pointed, if $f(x_0)=y_0$. A homotopy $H:X\times I\rightarrow Y$ is said to be based if it is a homotopy through based maps. That is the map $x\mapsto H(x,t)$ is a based map for each $t\in I$. In particular it satisfies $H(x_0,t)=y_0$, $\forall t\in I$.

In your case the homotopy $H:P\times I\rightarrow P$ must satisfy $H((0,1),t)=(0,1)$, $\forall t\in I$.

Comment: Ok. But according to the whole title of the exercise, I have to prove that exists $s\in [0,1]$ such that $H((0,1),s)=(0,0)$. I'm not looking for the fact that $H((0,1),t)=(0,1)$ for every $t \in [0,1]$.

Comment: If $H((0,1),s)=(0,0)$ for some $s\in I$ then it cannot hold that $H((0,1),t)=(0,1)$ for *all* $t\in I$. Hence if you can find such an $s$ then $H$ cannot be a based contraction of $P$.

Comment: There is a quick proof in Arkowitz's book "Introduction to Homotopy Theory" in example 1.4.5.4. (pg.11). Unfortunately its method is completely distinct from that offered by your professor, but maybe it'll give you a little insight into what is going on.